# Break outside the loop

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I am trying to run the following code. But every time I try to run it, the IDE says that the break is outside the loop

```
catname = []

print("Enter the name of the cats")

name = input()

if name == '':

   break

catname = catname+[name]

print("The cat Names are :")

for catname in name:

    print(name)
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: that's because `break` is not inside a loop :)

Comment: you have a break after an `if` statement and there's no loop in sight until the very end.

Comment: But the error message is misleading, one has to admit. As there is no loop, the break statement can't be outside of one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `break` when you want to `break` free from a loop, to exit the loop, to jump to the nearest code after the loop.

Your code *doesn't contain a loop*, so nothing to break free from, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

You use "break" just inside the loop ("for" or "while"), you are trying use brake inside the "if"

How about this:

```
if name != '':
    catname = catname+[name]
    print("The cat Names are :")
    for catname in name:
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your break statement is not in a loop, it's just inside an if statement.
But maybe you want to do something like the following.
If you want to let the user enter an random number of names and print the names out, when the user entered nothing, you can do the following:

```
# Here we declare the list in which we want to save the names
catnames = []

# start endless loop
while True:
    # get the input (choose the line which fits your Python version)
    # comment out the other or delete it
    name = input("Enter the name of a cat\n") # input is for Python 3
    # name = raw_input("Enter the name of a cat\n") # raw_input is for Python 2

    # break loop if name is a empty string
    if name == '':
       break

    # append name to the list catnames
    catnames.append(name)

print("The cat names are :")

# print the names
for name in catnames:
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `exit()`.

However, your code has also other problems, here is a piece of code that does what you probably want (when prompted, enter the names separated by spaces, like: Cat1 Cat2):

```
name = raw_input("Enter the name of the cats: ")

if len(name) == 0:
    exit()

print("\nThe cat Names are:")
for c_name in name.split():
    print(c_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the entirety of your code, then it's telling you exactly what the problem is:

```
catname = []

print("Enter the name of the cats")

name = input()

if name == '':

   break
```

You have a break statement in the code that's not contained inside a loop. What do you expect the code above to do?